# Tool to extract Type and Method signatures from namespace?

Tags: c#

I am looking to write a black box implementation of an existing Class Library: [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.aspx).

It would be very helpful if there was a tool to extract write stubs for all the types and method signatures without having to do it myself..

Comment: You're looking for ILSpy.

Comment: Also .Net Reflector (now from RedGate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can decompile source code and there are very application  such as [redgate](http://reflector.red-gate.com/Download.aspx).

Comment: thanks, wasn't looking for source, but I will cast my eyes aside :)